# How to write short title in two lines

Tags: header-footer

[image]

Hello, Please find below attachment for reference of my doubt.

I am using

```
\documentclass{singlecol-new}
\def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\LRH{xxxx, xxxxxx}

\RRH{Design And  Performance Metadata Based Management and Sharing of
    Distributed Biomedical Data}

\VOL{x}

\ISSUE{x}

\PUBYEAR{201X}

\BottomCatch

\CLline

\subtitle{}
```

In below figure SHORT TITLE is exceeding right border, I want Distinguished Biomedical Data (yellow colour marked) in next line.

`\\`, `\\*` , `\linebreak` are not working.

please help me in this

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Where can we get the`singlecol-new` cls file?

Comment: Yes, I got that from Inderscience journal website

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: Here is the link 
http://www.inderscience.com/info/inauthors/author_templates.php

Comment: Could you post the code which produced the image in your post?

Comment: \RRH{Design And  Performance Metadata Based Management and Sharing of Distributed Biomedical Data}. 
That command is used for displaying header of each page. I need to write that header in 2 lines because its exeeding right border. (\RRH is also called to display short title.). Please forget about image, I need to display header / short title to come in 2 lines

Comment: I need a full compilable code.

Comment: I sent you the link in that tex file is available. you have to download 9 ½" x 6 ½" LaTex format (template).

Comment: In that tex file, you can have compilable code. At starting you can find \RRH command which is used to display title for each page

Comment: I had downloaded the .cls file, and I have the template, but I don't have the .eps files. It makes it complex to compile.

Comment: Please comment all figures .eps. I don't want anything related to figures. Just glance title of each page.

Comment: Image which I posted relates to title of Journal Paper, not title of figure

Comment: A long title is automatically split in two lines.

Comment: Not Main Title of paper, please check each page short title, it is coming for me as I shown in image

Comment: Each page short title is exceeding my right border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
\RRH{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}\raisebox{4.2pt}[0pt]{\begin{tabular}{l}Design And Performance Metadata Based Management and Sharing of\\ Distributed Biomedical Data\end{tabular}}}%
```

[image]

Comment: Perfectly it's coming Sir. Thanks for your time. Can you please tell me what if I want to start second line (Distributed Biomedical Data) from left instead of centre?

Comment: I've posted  an improved version (as to vertical spacing) which is left-aligned.

Comment: I'm happy to have been useful! :o)